# "Python.exe has stopped working" with keyring module in Windows Vista

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-vista, python-keyring

I'm running Python 3.3.5 with [Keyring 3.8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) on an MS Vista SP2 machine. The issue occurs in both normal and safe mode. I've been running this same program on an XP SP3 machine without issue.

The part of the code that causes the problem is...

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("Test_Service","MyUser","Password123")
```

Python freezes and I get this error.

[image: Error.]

Clicking "close program" restarts the python shell.

The windows event viewer has this.

```
Faulting application pythonw.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x531c3653, 
faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18881, time stamp 0x51da3e27,
exception code 0xc0000374, fault     offset 0x000b06fc, process id 0x1104, 
application start time 0x01cf7d9df6c97176.
```

A quick google has [ntdll.dll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#NTDLL.DLL) as a windows API library.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? How to fix? Or whether there are alternate modules?

Edit: In the mean time I have ditched Keyring and decided to use a salted hash of the MachineGuid as a machine unique consistent password.